# 3D plot with warped colormap

Tags: python, matlab, visualization, data-visualization

An example (Matlab) code as follows:

```
Z = peaks(80); 
figure;     surf(Z);        colormap(jet)
figure;     imshow(mod(Z,pi),[],'i','f');        colormap(jet)
```

It generates:

- a 3D plot of the data `Z`
  [image: figure 1]
- a 2D view, where I warp `Z` into $\pi$:
  [image: figure 2]

I would like to combine the two, namely the *warped color map*: visualize `Z` in a 3D plot, but color it with the warped colormap (i.e. its height should refer to the 3D plot, but its color maps to the 2D plot).

How can I do it in either Matlab or Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the values on which the color should be based as a fourth input to [`surf`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html):

```
Z = peaks(80);
surf(1:size(Z,2), 1:size(Z,1), Z, mod(Z,pi))
colormap(jet)
```

[image]